# Change View : doesn't work events

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I use below code for change view (add view to main View) :

```
SearchCustomer *search=[[SearchCustomer alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchCustomer" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:search.view];
```

it works !

i put a button on SearchCustomer view but when i click on it event doesn't call but when i change view with below code it works too

```
SearchCustomer *search=[[SearchCustomer alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchCustomer" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:search animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `SearchCustomer` is a subclass of `UIViewController`.
That why when you `addSubview`, the `search` variable will be released. So there is no handler for the button event. With `presentViewController`, the `search` won't be released.

You should create a property for `SearchCustomer *search` if you want to use `addSubview`.

Comment: I have a main class , and i want add to it other class,for example add class 1 after that when user click on a button in class 1 remove class 1 and add class2 ...

Comment: Anyway, you have to create a pointer to handle the `SearchCustomer *search` with `strong` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can create property for SearchCustomer *search by using below code.

`@property(nonatomic,strong) SearchCustomer *search;`

You can add the search view to the main view by using below code.

`[self.view addSubview:self.search.view];`

It may helps you.